# How to transfer raw video data from a device to a computer using royalty free wired connection?

Tags: lcd, video

I have RGB video data captured from an LCD and I would like to send it over to a computer for capturing however it seems all video connectors require a significant investment if one intends to use them commercially (5k to 10k sign up + royalties for each product between $0.2 to $1). What connector could be suitable and be royalties free?

The data comes from two 256 × 192 LCDs, 18bit color depth, 60 frames per second.

Comment: VGA? 5xBNC? Ready made chip with built in royalty?

Comment: Also, make sure that you understand what royalties get you - sometimes the royalty just lets you put the official logo on the box. Your data rate is over 100Mbits, what video interfaces were you considering (aside from royalties)?

Comment: Were you considering compression royalties? Some of the older video codecs have had all their patents expire.

Comment: Probably a little tight in practice for USB2 HS unless you can optimize something in which case it should work, presumably possible as specified with USB3.  Look at how SDR projects do data streaming with USB FIFO chips that encapsulate the interface engine.

Answer (score 2):

Anything much wrong with SDI? Or Ethernet?

You are only looking for about 50Mb/s per screen, so simple Gb Ethernet will more then suffice, and even OLD school SD SDI could be leveraged as a physical layer with plenty of spare.

Hell, USB II would probably just about get her done, pain in the tail to implement compared to Ethernet however.

Regards, Dan.